# How to convert a video and audio file to be smoothly played via Media Source Extension API?

Tags: javascript, html, video, ffmpeg, media-source

I have built a web video player using the Media Source Extension API. I have been testing my video player using local video and audio files on my PC. Everything works perfectly expect the video keeps buffering. I'm playing a 4k 60fps video, which I downloaded from YouTube. My PC is not 4k resolution, but the video smoothly plays through YouTube and VLC Media Player. I'm just surprised to why my Media Source Extension Video Player buffers even through the video and audio file are not being retrieved via network. I'm assuming that the video and audio files I'm using are causing this problem. So I will explain how I created my video and audio files first:

1. I downloaded the video from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KaCQ8SQ6ZHQ&t=3s using the 4K Video Downloader https://www.4kdownload.com/products/product-videodownloader.
2. Convert the `mkv` (the 4K Video Downloader only allows the 4k 60fps video to be downloaded in `mkv` format, for me) file to `mp4` using `ffmpeg` in `CMD`: `ffmpeg -i test.mkv -codec copy test.mp4`.
3. Converting the `test.mp4` file to my preferred 4K resolution `3840x2160` from `3840x1632` using `ffmpeg` in `CMD`: `ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -s 3840x2160 -c:a copy test_changed.mp4`. (**NOT SO IMPORTANT**)
4. Separating the video and audio of `test_changed.mp4` to `video.mp4` for video and `audio.mp4` for audio using `MP4Box` in `CMD`: Video - `MP4Box -single 1 test_changed.mp4 -out video.mp4` and Audio - `MP4Box -single 2 test_changed.mp4 -out audio.mp4`.
5. Splitting both `video.mp4` and `audio.mp4` into 30 split parts each containing 5 seconds of the video and audio file. So I end up having (`video_1.mp4`,`audio_1.mp4`), (`video_2.mp4`,`audio_2.mp4`), (`video_3.mp4`,`audio_3.mp4`), ..... (`video_29.mp4`,`audio_29.mp4`), (`video_30.mp4`,`audio_30.mp4`). Using `ffmpeg` and one by one specifying the time range for each part in `CMD`:

   [For Part 1: `ffmpeg -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:05 -i video.mp4 video_1.mp4`, `ffmpeg -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:05 -i audio.mp4 audio_1.mp4`],

   [For Part 2: `ffmpeg -ss 00:00:05 -to 00:00:10 -i video.mp4 video_2.mp4`, `ffmpeg -ss 00:00:05 -to 00:00:10 -i audio.mp4 audio_2.mp4`],

   [For Part 3: `ffmpeg -ss 00:00:10 -to 00:00:15 -i video.mp4 video_3.mp4`, `ffmpeg -ss 00:00:10 -to 00:00:15 -i audio.mp4 audio_3.mp4`],

   .....

   [For Part 29: `ffmpeg -ss 00:02:20 -to 00:02:25 -i video.mp4 video_29.mp4`, `ffmpeg -ss 00:02:20 -to 00:02:25 -i audio.mp4 audio_29.mp4`],

   [For Part 30: `ffmpeg -ss 00:02:25 -to 00:02:30 -i video.mp4 video_30.mp4`, `ffmpeg -ss 00:02:25 -to 00:02:30 -i audio.mp4 audio_30.mp4`].
6. Fragmenting each of the video and audio parts using `MP4Box` in `CMD`(As far as I know, fragmented `mp4` files are only files played via Media Source Extension API):

   [For Part 1: `MP4Box -dash 1000 -rap -frag-rap video_1.mp4`, `MP4Box -dash 1000 -rap -frag-rap audio_1.mp4`],

   [For Part 2: `MP4Box -dash 1000 -rap -frag-rap video_2.mp4`, `MP4Box -dash 1000 -rap -frag-rap audio_2.mp4`],

   [For Part 3: `MP4Box -dash 1000 -rap -frag-rap video_3.mp4`, `MP4Box -dash 1000 -rap -frag-rap audio_3.mp4`],

   .....

   [For Part 29: `MP4Box -dash 1000 -rap -frag-rap video_29.mp4`, `MP4Box -dash 1000 -rap -frag-rap audio_29.mp4`],

   [For Part 30: `MP4Box -dash 1000 -rap -frag-rap video_30.mp4`, `MP4Box -dash 1000 -rap -frag-rap audio_30.mp4`].
7. I receive a fragmented file for each file with "_dashinit" being in it e.g. For Part 1: `video_1_dashinit.mp4` and `audio_1_dashinit.mp4`. These are the files I'm playing through Media Source Extension API.

So I'm appending these files into my `sourceBuffers` and playing it with the `video`. I have given the `test.zip` file here (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tyPBTxgpS601Xs5VEWznYhWw9PwhMHsB/view?usp=sharing) containing the test sample.

I'm using this command in `CMD` to run `Chrome` and test my file: `chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files`

Anyone can use this test sample and see if the video is buffering for them too. Please comment about anything I'm doing wrong, or help me construct a better 5 seconds video and audio files for `MSE` playable. Thanks

Comment: Your question is too broad

Comment: Wow, that's a huge amount of steps. Are you trying to just get the source video, split it into 5 second 'fragmented' chunks? Why are your separating the video and audio?

Comment: Also, STEP3 and STEP5 are both re-encoding the file again, using defaults, as you've set no parameters.

Comment: @video.baba I'm splitting the video into 5 seconds chunk, because thats how the MPEG-DASH works and I'm making my version of that. I'm going to be  making my video player switch audio from english to french and video from 2d format to 3d format. Thats why I'm having two source buffers. But I just want to know if the video player is lagging for other viewers too.

Comment: @cars chootu man

Comment: @video.baba Can you at least tell me if I'm using the right video and audio file for MSE.

Comment: Unfortunately, I know nothing of MSE. Don't know how I could test using that player/extension. I tried downloading the 4K video yesterday, also your test file, but without success, I'll try again. I can see the source video has a `3840x1632  2160p60 20334k , vp9, 60fps,` I'll try to get that with `m4a` audio.

Comment: I had a quick little read about the  [supported formats](https://w3c.github.io/media-source/byte-stream-format-registry.html) of Media source extensions. Have you tried downloading the Webm 4k file directly?

Comment: @video.baba Nope. Will webm file prevent my problem?